# How to generate SSH keys for gitlab.com hosted project?

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-keys, rsa, gitlab

I have a project hosted as private repository on gitlab.com. I want to use gitlab ci/cd to automatically deploy my project to remote server QA_SERVER when code is pushed to master branch. Below is the .gitlab-ci.yml content so far:

```
image: ubuntu:latest
stages:
  - deploy
deploy_QA:
  stage: deploy
  environment: 
    name: Staging
    url: "$QA_URL"
  before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - ssh-add <(echo "$PRIVATE_KEY")
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@"$QA_SERVER" 'rm -rf /var/www/html/*'
    - scp -P22 -r . ubuntu@"$QA_SERVER":/var/www/html
```

I need to generate private key and store as variable PRIVATE_KEY in gitlab project. How do I generate this key? Do I need to run ssh-keygen and where do I run it?

Note that the instruction given

[here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html)

are not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Link you provided gives all the information. Step by step:

1. On your local machine run `ssh-keygen`.

   - It is imporant that you do *not* protect your key with password - otherwise it cannot be used in non-interactive script.
   - It might be wise to use non default file path for keys. Lets assume its `~/.ssh/ubuntu_rsa`. Specific name doesn't matter.
2. As a result of key generation you will have 2 files in specified location: **ubuntu_rsa** and **ubuntu_rsa.pub**. For security reasons make sure **ubuntu_rsa** can be accessed only by you (e.g. `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/ubuntu_rsa`)
3. You need access to account on QA_SERVER that will be used by CI jobs  and it must be accessible via ssh - from script I assume its *ubuntu*
4. Use `ssh-copy-id` to add public key to QA_SERVER for *ubuntu*: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/ubuntu_rsa.pub ubuntu@QA_SERVER`. You will be prompted for *ubuntu* account password.
5. Add gitlab variable in your project - [see docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables). Lets assume its named SSH_PRIVATE_KEY and as a value set content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa` from your local machine.
6. script in your gitlab-ci.yml must have something like:

```
SRC_DIR=. # replace with whatever is needed here
echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY | ssh-add
scp -r $SRC_DIR ubuntu@QA_SERVER:/var/www/html
```